# The type 'QuickGraph.AdjacencyGraph<TVertex, TEdge>' exists in both ”*.dll“ and ”*.dll

Tags: c#

I am doing a Windows form application in C# and I get the following error. How can I sort it out?

> The type 'QuickGraph.AdjacencyGraph' exists in both 'c:\Users\amir\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Elearning recommender\packages\QuickGraph.3.3.51106.0\lib\net35\CodeContracts\QuickGraph.Contracts.dll' and 'c:\Users\amir\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Elearning recommender\packages\QuickGraph.3.3.51106.0\lib\net35\QuickGraph.dll'

Comment: I think you have to remove one of them from list of references. In the references right click on one of them and remove.

Comment: Do you use contracts?

Comment: Then you can remove reference to `Graph.Contracts.dll`.

Comment: thanks @M.kazemAkhgary. how I can be sure that I am not using that library('QuickGraph.Contracts.dll' or 'QuickGraph.dll') and if i delete it, does it make any problem?

Comment: they seem same to me. because probably same version. `QuickGraph.3.3.51106.0`. remove `QuickGraph.Contracts.dll` or other one. if you encounter problem remove the other.

Comment: Thanks @M.kazemAkhgary. the problem solved.

Comment: Thanks @HamletHakobyan. The problem solved